# How to select info from row above?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-cursor

I want to add a column to my table that is like the following:
This is just an example of how the table is structured, the real table is more than 10.000 rows.

```
No_   Name       Account_Type    Subgroup     (New_Column)
100   Sales      3               
200   Underwear  0               250          *100
300   Bikes      0               250          *100
400   Profit     3                             
500   Cash       0               450          *400
```

So for every time there is a value in 'Subgroup' I want the (New_Column) to get the value [No_] from the row above

```
No_   Name       Account_Type    Subgroup     (New_Column)
100   Sales      3               
150   TotalSales 3
200   Underwear  0               250          *150
300   Bikes      0               250          *150
400   Profit     3                             
500   Cash       0               450          *400
```

There are cases where the table is like the above, where two "Headers" are above. And in that case I also want the first above row (150) in this case.

Is this a case for a cursor or what do you recommend?

The data is ordered by No_

--EDIT--

Starting from the first line and then running through the whole table:
Is there a way I can store the value for [No_] where [Subgroup] is ''?
And following that insert this [No_] value in the (New_Column) in each row below having value in the [Subgroup] row. 
And when the [Subgroup] row is empty the process will keep going, inserting the next [No_] value in (New_Column), that is if the next line has a value in [Subgroup]

Here is a better image for what I´m trying to do:
[image]

Comment: I suggest proper normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: How do you define *the row above* ?? SQL Server doesn't have any "built-in" sorting - unless **you** explicitly specify an `ORDER BY` clause, there is no sorting - so there's no *row above* either....

Comment: Please expand a bit more on "where two "Headers" are above".  Please clarify both 'headers' and 'above' what.  I just don't get what you mean.  Thanks!

Comment: The row above in my case is the row above a value in [Subgroup). 
I was thinking to use a filter [where subgroup = '' ] somehow?

Comment: Actually the question is really not clear

Comment: @AceAlfred - people are trying to let you know that terms such as "above" are *meaningless* in SQL, unless *you* define a particular order (e.g. are they ordered by `No_`, for the purposes of this query?)

Comment: Sorry, they are ordered by No_

Comment: Do you want the (new_column) value to be the max(no_) where account_type <> 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 suggests using Window Offset Functions.
In this case : LAG

Something like this:

```
SELECT [No_]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Account_Type]
  ,[Subgroup]
  ,LAG([No_]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Subgroup]
ORDER BY [No_]) as [PrevValue]
FROM table
```

Here is an example from MS:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The ROW_NUMBER function will allow you to find out what number the row is, but because it is a windowed function, you will have to use a common table expression (CTE) to join the table with itself.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT [No_], Name, Account_Type, Subgroup, [Row] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [No_])
    FROM table
)
SELECT t1.*, t2.[No_]
FROM cte t1 
LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t1.Row = t2.Row - 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Those `ROW_NUMBER()` values are going to be assigned effectively randomly to the table. If the values in the CTE are assessed twice (as they may be with this self join), the `row_number`s assigned on the second pass are not guaranteed to correlate in any way with those from the first pass. In fact, it's within the realms of possibility that you could end up joining every row to itself.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: it would probably work, if the windowing function was defined as `over (order by [No_])` - it's about time that SQL Server also implements the `lag()` function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - oh, agreed. Ordering by a column that's unique in the underlying table is nice and predictable. Giving up and not defining an order is a great route to queries that work with sample data and then fail in production (either now, or 6 months down the line, or just intermittently)

Comment: The ORDER BY 1 indicates that it will sort by the first column in the table, not the integer (1).  All this is based on the assumption that the first column [No_] is a primary key, and produces the correct order desired for the "row above" criteria. I'll edit to make my windowing function less ambiguous.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This would be so easy if SQL Server finally supported the `lag()` windowing function as most other DBMS do...

Comment: @MattMurrell - in actual fact `ORDER BY 1` is invalid inside the `OVER()` and returns an error. `ORDER BY 1` may work as a plain `ORDER BY` clause, but it's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Next query will return Name of the *parent* row instead of the row itself, i.e. Sales for both Sales, Underwear, Bikes; and Profit for Profit, Cash:

```
select ISNULL(t2.Name, t1.Name)
from table t1
left join table t2 on t1.NewColumn = t2.No
```

Answer (score 0):

So in SQL Server 2008  i created test table with 3 values in it:

```
create table #ttable
(
    id int primary key identity,
    number int,
    number_prev int
)
Go
Insert Into #ttable (number) 
Output inserted.id
Values (10), (20), (30);
```

Insert in table, that does what you need (at least if understood correctly) looks like this:

```
declare @new_value int;
set @new_value = 13; -- NEW value
Insert Into #ttable (number, number_prev)
Values (@new_value, 
    (Select Max(number) From #ttable t Where t.number < @new_value))
```

[This part added] And to work with subgroup- just modify the inner select to filter out it:

```
Select Max(number) From #ttable t 
Where t.number < @new_value And Subgroup != @Subgroup
```

Comment: Actually you can avoid using temporary table, if create variable of type table: `declare @ttable table ( all the same )`

Comment: Why do you avoid using temporary tables? In this example its not important.

Comment: Because table variable stresses server much less then temp tables. So to increase useful load of your answer, it's better to propose the best solution you can in particular case. That will make SO more and more better.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      No_
    , Name 
    , Account_Type 
    , Subgroup 
    , ( SELECT MAX(above.No_) 
        FROM TableX AS above
        WHERE above.No_ < a.No_
          AND above.Account_Type = 3
          AND a.Account_Type <> 3
      ) AS NewColumn
FROM
      TableX AS a
```